# Как работать с autocomplete через selenum java

Tags: java, html, selenium, autocomplete

Стоит задача: вставить в `input` имя и из autocomplete появится меню, в котором надо выбрать нужное имя. Вот [сайт](http://schedule.npi-tu.ru/application/prep). И вот мой код:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://schedule.npi-tu.ru/application/prep");

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("fio_prep"));
element.sendKeys("Кирпиченкова Н В");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".ui-autocomplete")));
WebElement listItems = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-menu-item"));

listItems.click();

driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно не много пояснить в чем конкретно вопрос? Не происходит клика? Или Надо выбрать какого-то конкретного преподавателя из списка, например, водим Иванов, а выбираем именно Иванов А А? Если нам известно точно имя преподавателя, то такой код срабатывает на 100%, проверил сам. Код, на python, но т.к. всего 4 строки, думаю не будет сложно перевести его на используемый язык:

```
driver.get("http://schedule.npi-tu.ru/application/prep")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Преподаватели')))
driver.find_element_by_name('fio_prep').send_keys('Иванов И Ю')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-menu-item').click()
```

Comment: У меня не появлялось меню. После того как ввожу текст я пытался скачивать html страницу, но получал лишь исходный hrml код без меню

Comment: Меню, в смысле выпадающий список с преподавателями? В этом случае он не появляется, т.к. было событие `listItems.click();` и страница загружает расписание данного человека. Чтобы меню (выпадающий список) появились на странице с уже загруженный расписанием, можно очистить поле ввода имени и вставить его туда снова, в этом случае оно отобразится.

Comment: нет, я сейчас напис ваш код и вышла та же ошибка. Он не находит элемента 'ui-menu-item'. Выводит ошибку.

Comment: WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

        driver.get("http://schedule.npi-tu.ru/application/prep");

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Преподаватели")));
        driver.findElement(By.name("fio_prep")).sendKeys("Иванов И Ю");
        driver.findElement(By.className("ui-menu-item")).click();

        driver.quit();

Comment: Может быть просто не успевает подгрузиться список? Перед `driver.findElement(By.className("ui-menu-item")).click();` Поставь задержку в одну секунду

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Returned node was not a DOM element
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: Вот такая ошибка

Comment: Хоть я задержую на одну, хоть на десять. Все бестолку

Comment: Это, конечно, очень не правильно, но может быть стоит попробовать так:         driver.get("http://schedule.npi-tu.ru/application/prep")
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Преподаватели')))
        driver.find_element_by_name('fio_prep').send_keys('Иванов И Ю'+Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        driver.find_element_by_name('fio_prep').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-menu-item').click()

Comment: Бесполезно, ошибка идет на строке " driver.findElement(By.className("ui-menu-item")).click();"

Comment: А если вручную ввести часть имени? Будет выпадать список? Я клоню к тому, что может быть имеет смысл вводить часть имени `driver.find_element_by_name('fio_prep').send_keys('Кирпиченкова Н')` , а потом попробовать поиск по тексту и клик соответственно? `driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[text()='Кирпиченкова Н В']/..").click()`

Comment: WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

Comment: Проблема была в этом, тут надо было написать WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); Не знаю почему, но так работает